# Tomcat 6 Deploy Info Log on Startup

Tags: maven, tomcat, grails

I'm receiving an info log when trying to deploy my WAR package to Tomcat 6

> validateJarFile(< tomcat location >...\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.4.jar) - jar not loaded

This all started when I started to depend on remote Maven repos to compile dependencies.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'net.sourceforge.jtds:jtds:1.2.6'
    compile 'commons-codec:commons-codec:1.4'
    compile 'commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:3.1'
    compile 'jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17'
    compile 'ewsjavaapi:ewsjavaapi:1.2'
}
```

So my question is, could one of these JAR be pulling in a duplicate servlet-api jar which is causing this info log. If so, how does one find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate a [dependency report](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html) to find out.

Comment: I just performed this and found the culprit. jcifs is pulling in servlet-api. I was able to redeploy with `compile('jcifs:jcifs:1.3.17') {
            excludes 'servlet-api'
        }`